# how to sort binary by group using loop or pivot in R

Tags: r

```
A1=c("1","0","0","0","0")
A2=c("0","1","0","0","0")
B1=c("0","0","0","1","0")
B2=c("0","0","1","0","0")
C1=c("0","0","0","0","1")
C2=c("0","0","0","0","0")
K1=c("1","1","0","0","0")
K2=c("0","0","1","0","1")
K3=c("0","0","0","1","0")
df <- c(A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,K1,K2,K3)
```

HOW CAN I SORT A1 HAVE HOW MANY K1 K2 K3;A2 HAVE HOW MANY K1,K2,K3;... C2 have how many K1, K2,K3?

initially i use

```
if(df$A1==1 && df$K1==1){
    a=a+1; ##a=0
    print(a);
} else if(df$A1==1 && df$K2==1){
    b=b+1;
    print(b)
} else if(df$A1==1 && df$K3==1){
    c=c+1;
    print(c)
} else if(df$A2==1 && df$K1==1){
    d=d+1; 
    print(d);
} else if(df$A2==1 && df$K2==1){
    e=e+1;
    print(e)
} else if(df$A2==1 && df$K3==1){
    f=f+1;
    print(f)
}else if(df$B1==1 && df$K1==1){
    g=g+1; 
    print(g);
} else if(df$B1==1 && df$K2==1){
    H=H+1;
    print(H)
} else if(df$B1==1 && df$K3==1){
    I=I+1;
    print(I)
}
```

but it will be too long and again it does not work... How can i improve my coding using for loop or other function i donot know?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matrix multiplication:

```
df<-type.convert(df)
t(as.matrix(df[1:6])) %*% as.matrix(df[7:9])
   K1 K2 K3
A1  1  0  0
A2  1  0  0
B1  0  0  1
B2  0  1  0
C1  0  1  0
C2  0  0  0
```

Comment: if my df has 100 * 9, how can i get the result and count A1 have how many K1 K2 respectively?

Comment: @SknU exactly what I provided

Comment: likewise if i wish to calculate K1 have how many 0s that belong B1 B2... instead of using df1 <- t(as.matrix(df[1:6])) %*% as.matrix(df[7:9]) and filter K1==0 and B1===0 then calculated the cummulative counts how should i refine my coding?